# Getting error when installing ubuntu 18.10 on solid hard drive

Tags: system-installation, ssd

I have just purchased a solid adata su650 hard drive. I try to install Ubuntu 18.10 without success.

When starting the installation process and after creating the user, the installer stops and sends a message that verifies the usb or the disk.

I checked that AHCI in BIOS is enabled by default.

The motherboard is Asrock H61M-VG3.

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Thank you

**Update 1: Error message**

The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

[Errno 5] Input/Output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty HD....

At the console area messages like

```
SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block XXXXXXX
SQUASHFS error: zlib decompresion failed, data probably corrupt
SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block XXXXXXX
...
```

**Update 2: Solution**

In the end it turned out to be a problem with the usb stick. After acquiring a new usb stick and making it bootable the process concluded as excpected.

Thank you all for the comments

Comment: AHCI  is an option in most BIOS/UEFI setup utilities. Enter BIOS/UEFI and enable AHCI.  Advanced -> IDE Configuration -> SATA options -> AHCI or it may be different for Asrock's BIOS.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is a firmware update for that drive? Many need updates to work.

Comment: I have not check this, how can I do this?

Comment: You've probably got a bad Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Use md5sums or sha1sums to verify your .iso download that you used to build the Live media. If it checks OK, then your DVD/USB media is defective, or needs to be recreated.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, right now I am downloading a new iso instance to try with a new usb. I let you know what happen